# Use an array of variables in an each mixin

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to write an array for a variable to be used in an "each" statement.

```
        $array: (("1", "../../Media/Images/FirstImage.png"), ("2", "../../Media/Images/SecondImage.png"));

        @each $i in $array {
          &:nth-child( #{$i} ) {
            a {
              &:before {
                content: "";
                background: url({This is the 2nd part of each variable}) no-repeat;
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have an array of arrays, not a single-dimensional array of variables or values. It seems like you could change your array to be 1-dimensional, and just use the index for the `:nth-child()`.

```css
$urls: ("../../Media/Images/FirstImage.png", "../../Media/Images/SecondImage.png");


@each $url in $urls {
  $i: index($urls, $url);
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    a {
      &:before {
        content: "";
        background: url($url) no-repeat;
      }
    }
  }
}
```